# how to get all Editable field values using jquery on button click

Tags: jquery

I have some dropdownlist boxes in my field set if I change any field in the Fieldset I need to catch the value of changed dropdownlist?

Can I do this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jquery selector should look something like this

```
$("fieldset#idOfSpecificFieldSet select")
```

you can then iterate though each select element like this

```
$("fieldset#idOfSpecificFieldSet select").each(function() {
   alert($(this).val());  //iterate though select elements and alert the value
});
```

as for attaching a button click  you could do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(buttonselector).click(function() {
    $("fieldset#idOfSpecificFieldSet select").each(function() {
       alert($(this).val());  //iterate though select elements and alert the value
    });
  })

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like along these lines...

```
$('select').change(
   function(){
     $(this).val()
    }
);
```

You can change the selector to match all selects under your field set too...